# Codeanywhere.com - Angular Stack

Tags: angular, codeanywhere

I have previously used codeanywhere for quickly spinning up and running Angular projects for testing code.

It seem now that they don't provide these container now and just a Node stack option.

I tried to install Angular using npm on this stack but it didn't allow.

Has anyone come across this and is there a workaround as it used to be a great option/container to have on codeanywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I did the following to create an Angular container on Codeanywhere:

1. Create a Node.js - Ubuntu 16.04 Container.
2. Update Packages: `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y`
3. Update npm: `npm install -g npm`
4. Run `npm install -g @angular/cli`

Angular should be installed now.